# NCalc expression.evaluate output different from when I compute the expression manually

Tags: math, expression, ncalc

Here is my code:

```
Dim ex As String = "(((105 * 4000) * 0.20) - ((0 + 10000) * (105 * 4000)) / ((105 * 4000) + Round((52 * 18192.31),0))) / 24"
Dim x As New Expression(ex)
Dim result As Decimal = x.Evaluate
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString("N"))
```

it returns: **3,502.90**, but when i compute it manually and thru excel the output I get is: **3371.888737**

Here is the image of my manual computation...

[Manual Computation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzNs4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`3,502.90 * 24 = 84089.6`

It is bigger than the first addend. And the second should be positive.

But you have **overflow** of 32-bit integer arithmetics in this expression

```
(0 + 10000) * (105 * 4000) = 4 200 000 000 > 2^31-1
```

That is why the second addend becomes negative (and a1-(a2) > a1)

Probably it is enough to use doubles like this:

```
  (0.0 + 10000) * (105.0 * 4000)
```

*P.S. You don't execute rounding in manual writing*